# Angular 2 - Number to String Conversion using pipe

Tags: angular, pipe

I am trying to convert a number value to a string in angular 2 using typescript within a pipe. It complains

> Type string is not assignable to type number

. My pipe is as follows.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'pxsuffix'

}) export class pxsuffix implements PipeTransform {

transform(input: number): number {

if ((input > 0)) {
    input = input.toString(),
}

return (
    input = input + 'px',

);
}
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Your function is asking for returning a Number and you are returning a String. Try:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'pxsuffix'

}) export class pxsuffix implements PipeTransform {

transform(input: number): string{ //string type
   return input + 'px';
} }
```

Comment: Can you please accept the answer and up vote it so other people can use it?